# Can't retrieve get parameters using Request class

Tags: symfony

I have a simple blog bundle with the following route:

```
blog_post:
    pattern:  /blog/{year}/{month}/{filename}/
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBlogBundle:Post:index }
    requirements:
        year: "[0-9]{4}"
        month: "[0-9]{2}"
        filename: "([^/.]+)"
```

which matches the url of `symfony.local/blog/2012/04/hello-world/` without a problem. However for some reason I am unable to access the query parameters using the Request class as below:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


    print_r($request->query->keys()); // outputs blank array
    print_r($request->request->keys()); // outputs blank array

    echo $request->get('filename'); // outputs hello-world

    ....

   }
```

Can anyone explain why I'm unable to access the query parameters using `$request->query->get('filename');`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `$request->query` only contains parameters that are passed as query strings (`GET` parameters only) not those defined as route parameters (which are attributes parsed from the `PATH_INFO`)

So, you can use both,

```
$request->attributes->get('parameterName');
$request->get('parameterName');
```

to access url parameters.

**In fact**, when using [`$request->get('XXXX')`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/53fad04f3e7cdcd37a0a4b0c225c3e8c25078b78/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L527), it checks all the parameters bags ($request->query, $request->request and $request->attributes) until it founds one that fit the given name.

Comment: I see. I thought that might be the case; thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: I was hesitant to use `$request->get('paramName');` as I would rather explicitly state which bag to use for the reason of best practice; and now I know why I couldn't access it via the query bag :)